# Set texture of all materials

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I get all the materials from a gameObject (Some have 5-10 materials) and set the same texture to each of these materials?

```
public GameObject go;
public Texture texture;
void Start()
{
 go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("_BaseMap", texture);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the way to do this. By getting all materials into an array.

```
 Material[] myMaterials = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().materials;
        for (int i = 0; i < myMaterials.Length; i++) {
            myMaterials[i].SetTexture ("_BaseColorMap", texture);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

public GameObject go,go1,go2;
Try it this way